# SQL Query for Data Copy to Other Field

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, copy, sql-update

i have use a db for my school records and update them every month like inspection data for every month observed performance for students.

my question is...

i have enrollment table as per my school register

```
Class:                Cls_1,Cls_2,Cls_3,...
Enrolled Students      30     40    50  ...
Present Students       10     20    30  ...
```

So, i want                  (Column)    cls_1   cls_2   cls_3
copy enrolled students      (Register)   30      40      50       to Present Student by query.

that my results will show

```
Class:                Cls_1,Cls_2,Cls_3,...
Enrolled Students      30     40    50  ...
Present Students       30     40    50  ...
```

Comment: What did you try until now?

Comment: Your question is tagged both [tag:mysql] (a free, open-source, cross-platform RDBMS product now owned by Oracle) and [tag:sql-server] (a competing, proprietary, commercial RDBMS product from Microsoft).  Which are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this you want?

```
INSERT INTO enrollment
select 'Present Students', [Cls_1],[Cls_2],[Cls_3] from enrollment
WHERE class='Enrolled Students'
```